# Is it safe to use a new microwave if I dropped it on the back corner?

Tags: equipment, microwave

I dropped my brand new microwave transferring right out of the box and before use. It landed on the back right corner. The frame is bent, but it doesn't look like anything else is wrong. I don't know if I can still use it; is it safe to just try it?

Comment: Welcome to the site! I took your name out of your question to protect your privacy. Feel free to put it on your [profile page](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/users/43768/user43768) if you'd like. Check out our [tour] and [help] pages to learn more about our site so you can have the most fun here. Did your microwave come with an owner's manual? They usually have a phone number for you to call and ask your questions, just to make sure you're safe. I hope it's fine, but I wouldn't want anything bad to happen to you!

Comment: If your question isn't getting the desired answers here, consider flagging it to ask a moderator to migrate the question to http://electronics.stackexchange.com/ or possibly http://diy.stackexchange.com.  On either of those, more people might have relevant expertise.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether or not this question is really on-topic here.  But the basic answer is that microwaves generally have a lot of safeguards built in to avoid radiation leakage, if that's what you're worried about.  The [FDA states](http://www.fda.gov/Radiation-EmittingProducts/ResourcesforYouRadiationEmittingProducts/ucm252762.htm#Checking_Ovens_For_Leakage):

> There is little cause for concern about excess microwaves leaking from
>   ovens unless the door hinges, latch, or seals are damaged. In FDA's
>   experience, most ovens tested show little or no detectable microwave
>   leakage. If there is some problem and you believe your oven might be
>   leaking excessive microwaves, contact the oven manufacturer, a
>   microwave oven service organization, your state health department, or
>   the nearest FDA office.

So, if only very minor exterior damage was done, and there was no damage to the door or seals, it seems unlikely there would be a problem.

On the other hand, [WHO recommends](http://www.who.int/peh-emf/publications/facts/info_microwaves/en/):

> The design of microwave ovens ensures that the microwaves are
>   contained within the oven and can only be present when the oven is
>   switched on and the door is shut. Leakage around and through the glass
>   door is limited by design to a level well below that recommended by
>   international standards. However, microwave leakage could still occur
>   around damaged, dirty or modified microwave ovens. It is therefore
>   important that the oven is maintained in good condition. Users should
>   check that the door closes properly and that the safety interlock
>   devices, fitted to the door to prevent microwaves from being generated
>   while it is open, work correctly. The door seals should be kept clean
>   and **there should be no visible signs of damage to the seals or the
>   outer casing of the oven. If any faults are found or parts of the oven
>   are damaged, it should not be used until it has been repaired by an
>   appropriately qualified service engineer.**

Basically, I can't know how much damage and/or what type of damage you did by dropping it.  (And no one else here could know for certain either.)  Microwaves are generally designed in such a way to prevent radiation exposure except in cases of severe damage or deliberate disassembling, but I have no idea what may have happened internally to your device by dropping it.

If you're concerned about other safety issues (electrical shorts, etc.), it would be even more speculative to try to address whether or not they could happen with these few details.

Answer (score 0):

Magnetron shoots its microwave output down a waveguide into your oven. This gets nowhere near the back right corner. I'd use it without worry. If paranoid, you might want to tape a layer of aluminum foil around the dent. Be certain the door opens and closes properly. If that's gotten bent, you **do** have a problem.